# TFS Work Item Template - Cannot Remove Activated Field Rules from Initial Transition

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have modified a 'BUG' work item template to include an initial state of 'Proposed' rather than 'Active'.  The initial transition used on item creation has two unwanted Field Rules:  Activated By' and 'Activated Date'.  I've tried unsccessfully to remove them and save the workflow, but they continue to regenerate.  Has anyone encountered this behavior before?

I've exhausted MSDN and other forums tyring to find an answer, so I thought it was time to turn to the Stack community for some advice.

[image]

Comment: What techniques have you used to try to remove them?

Comment: Using the designer to open the transition, selecting the rules and deleting them as I would / have with other transition fields.  It appears as a problem only with the initial transitions, works correctly with all others.  I have not attempted to use power tools or the command line to accomplish this as I've encountered permissions issues with that in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the [Process Editor in the power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) to remove those or you can use the [witadmin command line utility to achieve this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243889.aspx).

You cannot use this designer canvas to modify the rules for a work item type.

Comment: The picture may not have been clear, but I am using the Process Editor to manage the work item workflow.  I am able to change all rules and transitions including the initial transition using the tool.  For some reason, changes specifically to the Activated by and Date revert back on the initial transition after saving.  This only occurs for the initial transition and those specific rules.

Comment: I've marked this as an answer because i ended up editing the XML manually and importing the work item back into the project.  That said, I was able to use the designer to update all other transtion states and rules.